# Home is not an Enclosing class

Tags: android, class, imagebutton

I am trying to put the Image button in another class but...Ive never used classes so i don't exactly know what im doing. It says that "Home" is not an enclosing class. what does this mean? How do i prevent this? This will also help in the future to make the main activities code easier to read in classes instead of having it all in one file.

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;

public class Options_menu implements View.OnClickListener {

private ImageButton options_menu;
private WebView webView;



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    options_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Home.this, options_menu);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, 
 popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new 
 PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.back:
                            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                                webView.goBack();
                            } else {
                                webView.reload();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case R.id.forward:
                            if (webView.canGoForward()) {
                                webView.goForward();
                            } else {
                                webView.reload();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case R.id.refresh:
                            webView.reload();
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the line `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Home.this, options_menu);`. You can only do this from inside the `Activity class Home`. The `PopupMenu` class constructor `PopupMenu (Context context, View anchor)` requires a context to be passed in. When you use  `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Home.this, options_menu);` from inside the `Activity class Home`, `Home.this` passes as a context but from outside it does not. You need to pass in context to your class if you want to create the PopupMenu in here